# Java Regex for Removing Year in Date Pattern String

Tags: java, regex, string, date

I'm trying to create a reg expression to find a sequence of the char 'y' and a '/' before or after it. But only if nothing is after or before the '/' characters. This is better explained with examples.  Basically, I need to remove these from the String.

For example:

'dd/MM/yyyy' becomes 'dd/MM'
'dd/yy/MM' becomes 'dd/MM'
'y/MM/dd' becomes 'MM/dd'

Is this even possible with Regex?  And if it isn't, what's the best way to approach this? Just if-then logic?

Comment: Why you want to do this with regex?

Comment: Why don't you try to dot it?

Comment: If theres a better way than regex then I'd do that instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
String replacement = inputString.replaceAll("/y+|y+/","");
```

Answer (score 1):

What about replacing: `\/y+|y+\/` with nothing?